# Visual Basic Deleting Unmodified Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The following code will extract files from one Folder and Place them another as you can see. But I am trying to delete the files that have not been modified in the past 3 months, and it does not delete any files at all.

Code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

    Dim txtFiles1 As Control

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "E:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "E:\FilesExtracted"

        Try
            Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

            If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory)) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
            End If

            For Each currentFileLoc As String In txtFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFileLoc.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                File.Move(currentFileLoc, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))

                Try
                    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory)
                    Dim fi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()

                    For Each currentFile As FileInfo In fi
                        File.Move(currentFile.FullName, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, currentFile.Name))

                        Dim dt As DateTime = currentFile.LastWriteTime
                        ' Add 3 months to the last write and check if it is less than today '
                        If dt.AddMonths(3) < DateTime.Today Then
                            File.Delete(currentFile.FullName)

                        End If
                    Next
                Catch eT As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
                End Try

            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, deleting a file *after* you moved it isn't going to work well.

Comment: Thank You for your Global insight, sir. So how can I initially delete the certain files, then extract only the files that I need